# NPGSQL SSL With Client Certificate and Key Files

Tags: npgsql

I am attempting to create a C# application that connects to a PostgreSQL database using SSL with client certificate and key files similar in functionality to the PGAdmin UI, but the documentation for this in NPGSQL is lacking and I cannot find any examples. The [documentation](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html#encryption-ssltls) states that it "works just like on .NET's SSLStream", but I am not seeing any correlation between the two. Has anyone created a connection using this method that can possibly provide some help?

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same situation. Documentation certainly needs to describe usage explicitly on how to supply cert, key and CA files if needed to the connection string or connection builder, and how the ProvideClientCertificatesCallback can actually supply back cert, key and CA files.

Nov 2018: I got below sample code to work for self-signed certs:

```
var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
connection.ProvideClientCertificatesCallback += clientCerts => this.GetMyClientCertificates(clientCerts);

private void GetMyClientCertificates(X509CertificateCollection clientCerts)
{
    clientCerts.Add(<supply an instance of X509Certificate2 here>);
}
```

Comment: How do you get an x509 certificate from the .crt and .key files typically used with postgres?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `SSL=true` in your connection stream, and then provide a `ProvideClientCertificatesCallback` on your NpgsqlConnection before opening it (like SSLStream).

Comment: I see that in the documentation, but that doesn't appear to work with unregistered certificate files, specifying the client certificate and key files.